# Anyone can register via backend

Tags: php

My question is simple.

Is it possible to enable option "**Anyone can register**" with php function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use following in PHP:

```
update_option( 'users_can_register', $value );
```

Where $value can be **1** for `Yes` and **0** for `No`